# How to proper import Timestamp class from firebase (8+) using Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was using firebase 7.16.1 and I was importing and declaring a property as Timestamp this way:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';

export class CourseEventMessage {
  sentTimestamp: firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

But after upgrading to firebase 8.1.2, the import is getting an error:

```
Module '"../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?ts(2614)
```

I've tried the following imports, all of them imports ok, but no Timestamp exists on the import.

```
import firestore from "../../../node_modules/firebase"; 
import firestore from 'firebase';
import firestore from 'firebase/app';
```

The only way I could found that imports Timestamp was:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export class CourseEventMessage {
    sentTimestamp: firebase.default.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

So what's the proper way to import the Timestamp class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In v8, all of the types for all Firebase products should come from "firebase/app".  It's typical to start an import like this, as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) for module bundlers:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
```

Do NOT use the old form from v7:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"  // this no longer works the way you expect
```

[Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) can be found in `firebase.firestore.Timestamp`.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export class CourseEventMessage {
    sentTimestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

If you want to abbreviate that a bit, use a type alias:

```
type Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
export class CourseEventMessage {
    sentTimestamp: Timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For v9 its:
import {  Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

Answer (score 0):

It took me ages to find the right solution for v9, hope it helps someone. You don't need the whole "firebase.firestore.FieldValue...", what works is actually much easier:

```
import { updateDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const updateTimestamp = await updateDoc(docRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```